# Displaying complete credit card information to end user

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

I am using an ecommerce website that accepts and stores CC information. In the webpage, they show only the last 4 digits (which is perfectly fine). But when I intercept the request/response, I could see the complete CC number as part of one API response. Anyways they don't show security code/CVV.

1. Does sending complete CC number to end user violate PCI compliance?
2. What are the issues this might cause? I could think of only one scenario - If the account is compromised, attacker can get the complete card number and he can brute force the CVV or use the number on sites that doesn't require CVV.

Comment: Is this in relation to a “saved cards” kind of page?  Or during the payment itself?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are saying that the web application masks the user's credit card, but that masking is only in the client-side UI; the server passes the full card back to the user at the API level.

I don't think this is technically a violation of the PCI DSS, because it is in fact masking displayed data, but it's clearly a violation of best practices and I would not be surprised if a QSA found it to be a violation.  Most stores are very careful never to "play back" the full PAN to a user, in case an attacker manages to get access to the account.